# "unresolved external symbol" on template specialization for array of char

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, template-specialization

I have something like this in my code:

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
  void Print();
};

template <>
struct A<char*>
{
  void Print() { printf("Char*!\n"); }
};

template <typename T>
void DoSomething(T& lol)
{
  A<T> a;
  a.Print();
}

int main()
{
  char a[5];
  DoSomething(a);
}
```

And this produces the following linker error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall A<char [5]>::Print(void)" (?Print@?$A@$$BY04D@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl DoSomething<char [5]>(char const (&)[5])" (??$DoSomething@$$BY04D@@YAXAAY04$$CBD@Z)
```

What type should I specialize the A template for, so that I can use it with a array-of-char? I tried `const char*` and other combinations of const, char, * and &, and nothing works.

Note that I cannot change the `DoSomething` function.

Also, if possible, I would like the compiler to automatically deduce (or convert) the template type without specifying it in the `DoSomething<smth>()` call in `main()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a` does not have type `char*`, it has type `char[5]`, so the primary template is instantiated, not the specialization.

If you manually perform the array-to-pointer conversion, it will use the specialization:

```
char a[5];
char* aptr = a;
DoSomething(a);
```

If you don't want the primary template to be used for a `char` array, you can specialize the template:

```
template <unsigned N> struct A<char[N]> { /* ... */ };
```

Comment: What if I can't (or really, really do not want to) perform the array-to-pointer conversion?

Comment: @Kronikarz:  Then you need to specialize the template for an array type.

Answer (score 1):

You could just follow the compile error and specialize for `char[5]`.

```
template <>
struct A<char*>
{
  void Print() { printf("Char*!\n"); }
};
```

It seems like a very strange specialization to provide, though.

If you want to explicitly specify a which specialization of `DoSomething` to use, then why not do exactly that?

```
int main()
{
  char a[5];
  DoSomething<char *>(a);
}
```

Of course, you'll find that this still doesn't compile as `DoSomething` takes a non-const reference so you need an lvalue of type `char *`, a temporary won't do.

```
int main()
{
  char a[5];
  char *p = a;
  DoSomething<char *>(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char a[5];
char* aPointer = &a[0];
DoSomething(aPointer);
```

This will pass a char* to DoSomething.

Here is your complete sample code, modified to do this correctly:

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
  void Print();
};

template <>
struct A<char*>
{
  void Print() { printf("Char*!\n"); }
};

template <typename T>
void DoSomething(T& lol)
{
  A<T> a;
  a.Print();
}

int main()
{
  char a[5];
  char* aPointer = &a[0];
  DoSomething(aPointer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility to force array->pointer decay would be creating a specialization of `DoSomething`:

```
template <typename T>
void DoSomething(const T& lol)
{
  A<T> a;
  a.Print();
}

template <class T, unsigned N>
void DoSomething(T(& x)[N])
{
  DoSomething(x+0);
}
```

(you should make the parameter of `DoSomething` `const` since nonconst reference cannot work as a reference if you pass arrays to it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd have though that providing an explicit specialization of `DoSomething` might count as "changing the `DoSomething` function". Changing it's parameter from `T&` to `const T&` certainly does.